# What is the best practice for fetching a user's association with many other elements in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Understanding the speed of Firestore reads, I'm curious what others Firestore *users* do when they need to take a current object (in my case a user) and see how that user relates to many other objects (other documents).

My use case currently is a user signs in and goes to see a list of items (5 items on initial page load). Each item has many options like "Liked" or "Favorited."

To see if a user has liked each item, I can either store a single document containing a list of all items a user liked for each category of items, or I can make a call to fetch the document storing the "user A liked item X" which would be numberOfItems * numberOfValues (e.g. 5 items, each item has 3 different boolean options).

Curious what others do in this case to keep document read count tamed.

Comment: Why not keep `liked` as boolean in the `item` document? Assuming you have a collection `items` for every user. I think the general strategy is to organize your data according to the queries that will be performed.

Comment: It's a good idea but currently the user is going to a generate list of items, so it's not unique to the user (e.g. a list of all books, rather than a list specific to the user).

Comment: I had a similar problem a while ago. I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI helpful. Also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ

Comment: What did you end up doing? Seems a lot of folks will tell you to sync your data multiple times across while other approaches (and what seems like the Firebase team's suggestion) is to just call every document every time. Seems excessive but trying to minimize calls (cost conscious)

Comment: My case doesn't directly translate, but to translate roughly, I ended up storing the ids of the `liked` items and important things like their names inside the user document. That way I can populate the main view immediately. When the user clicks on an item, I can fetch the full document for that item with one document read. Keeping the name in sync between multiple collections involves multiple writes, but renaming an item doesn't happen often.

Comment: I think that's what I'll end up doing. For each category, I can store the items for the user. Seems like making one doc call for the fetching will outweigh the potential of many tens of reads with the alternative approach. Thanks!

Comment: On a second thought, this approach might prove to be brittle in a real app. For example, if you later wanted to show how many users liked a certain item you would need the `like` to exist in its own collection anyway. The nice thing about firebase queries is that you are only charged for the number of results. So fetching all the likes for a particular user would be fairly cheap and fast if it's indexed by uid.

Comment: Turns out there’s a minimum charge of one read per query rather than the number of results for empty queries